# Spring JPA MYSQL Date off by one day

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working with a spring boot project that connects to a local MySQL database with JPA. I have an table with a `DATE` column that is mirrored in the JPA model class as `private Date myDate;` and is of type `java.sql.Date;`. When I display the records in the project on a page the date is one day behind (e.g. if it is 2021-01-25 then the page shows 2021-01-24) and when I update or add the record through the project the newly selected date is also one day behind the date I select. I have tried to add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone : CET` but this doesn't have any effect. I display the record like this `${record.myDate}` on the page and on the form like this:

```
<fieldset>
   <form:label path="myDate">Date *</form:label>
   <form:input path="myDate" type="date" required="required" class="form-control"/>
   <form:errors path="myDate" cssClass="text-warning" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL documentation says that:

> MySQL stores TIMESTAMP in UTC value. However, MySQL stores the
> DATETIME value as is without timezone.

So, it seems likely that when you retrieve your data value from the database via JPA, it's being assigned a timezone that is not what you expect (probably the default timezone in the context of where the code is being executed - your application server).

I think that to make this work properly, you would probably need to use a `TIMESTAMP` column in MySQL instead of a `DATETIME`.

Once you make that change, you should probably also use `LocalDateTime` instead of `Date`.
JPA has support for LocalDateTime - use the following column definition:

```
@Column(name = "my_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime myDateTime;
```